# Table with collapsed groups of rows, help me get the first group open by default

Tags: jquery, html

See [Link!](https://jsfiddle.net/sinnix/y5j463Lg/)

I have a snippit of code which I've pieced together from various other stackoverflow questions.

It is a table which has collapsing groupings of row. Each group is preceded by a special row with a "header" class. Right now, each group is automatically hidden on load and you can click on the heading to expand the section. What I would like to do is have the first grouping always open on page load.

```
$('.table-squish tbody tr').hide().filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('td[colspan]').length;
}).addClass('header')
    .css('display', 'table-row')
    .click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').css('display', function (i, v) {
        return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just trigger the initial click of it onload.

```
 $('.header:first').trigger('click');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y5j463Lg/1/)